# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'type'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
T=[int]*100

N=int(input("Enter an integer "))

while not 2<=N<=100:

    N=int(input("Enter an integer "))

for i in range(N):

    T[i]=int(input("Enter strictly increasing numbers "))

    while not int(T[i]) < int(T[i+1]):

        T[i]=int(input("Enter strictly increasing numbers "))

for i in range(N):

    if T[i]!=T[i+1]+1:

        print(T[i]+1)
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/WesternDigital/Desktop/probthlatha.py", line 7, in <module>     while not T[int(i)]<T[int(i+1)]: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'type'`

I tried changing T[i] with int(T[i]) but that would just return this error instead: (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'type')

Comment: `T=[int]*100` -- what do you think that does?  Remember that you've only input `i` numbers, so `i+1` is coming from that list.  And you do not need to call the `int` cast on things that are already integers.

Comment: Please repost the code with proper code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `T` is a list where all of the elements are **the class** `int`. Therefore, when you are comparing `T[i]` and `T[i+1]`, one of them is a number, but the other one is still the `int` class. You should initialize `T` to an array of numbers, such as by doing `[0] * 100`.

Your problem with the infinite loop is caused in this section of code:

```py
for i in range(N):

    T[i]=int(input("Enter strictly increasing numbers "))

    while not int(T[i]) < int(T[i+1]): # << logical error here

        T[i]=int(input("Enter strictly increasing numbers "))
```

You need to change your condition to `not T[i] > T[i-1]`. That will fix both errors, because the program is referencing previously entered numbers in the condition, not the `int` class or an element that hasn't been assigned to.

Comment: Isn't the int class the same as a number??

Comment: Now when I want to input T[i], I can correctly enter my numbers, but it goes indefinitely, meaning it does not stop at N

Comment: `int` is the class. Numbers are instances of `int`

Comment: Where does it infinitely repeat?

Comment: for i in range(N):

        T[i]=int(input("Enter strictly increasing numbers "))
Now normally if I would set N=4 I would input four numbers in the T array, but I can input numbers forever

Answer (score 0):

I can't guess what you intended that second loop to do, but here's how you can input your numbers with validation.  Note that I don't pre-initialize the array; I build it on the fly.

```
T=[]
N=int(input("Enter an integer "))
while not 2<=N<=100:
    N=int(input("Enter an integer from 2 to 100")) 
for i in range(N):
    T.append( int(input("Enter strictly increasing numbers ") ))
    while i and not T[i] > T[i-1]:
        T[-1]=int(input("No, enter strictly increasing numbers "))
for i in range(N):
    if i and T[i]!=T[i-1]+1:
        print(T[i]+1)
```